# Git workflow with pull requests and incremental work

Tags: git, rebase, pull-request, git-merge-conflict

In our team we are working alone on branches, do some pull requests which can take as long as 24h delay to be merged, and we use rebase.

Now let's say I'm on feature-A-1, created from dev, everything's nice and can go in production.
I do a merge request.
Now I want to continue on feature-A, 2nd part. For this I need to build on top of feature-A-1. Since feature-A-1 is not merged, I must create a branch from feature-A-1, and cannot create it from dev.
That's what I do, and commit happily on feature-A-2.

When feature-A-1 is merged into dev, comme the time to rebase feature-A-2 on dev, and it's a catastrophe: commit conflicts like crazy, and files I'm the only one to have touched do conflict. It's like the commits where applied in a "reverse" order, old version of code conflicting with new version of code.

So:
- It would be interesting for me to know what happens here. I can't wrap my head around this problem.
- And more importantly I would need any insight on how to either solve that problem, or change my workflow.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is broad, but the sanest thing here would be to not branch off a feature branch which is pending a merge.  There are even other problems beyond what you mentioned, namely a bug may turn up in the pending feature branch which would then have to be fixed in multiple places.

Comment: Just don't rebase. Issue a pull requenst for `feature-A-2` as usual, which of course has to be merged after `feature-A-1` was merged.